# Pusher in php - Do not send events [ Unknown auth_key]

Tags: php, pusher

I am using the following code:

```
 require('pusher-http-php-master/lib/Pusher.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$app_id = '*'; 
$app_key = '*';
$app_secret = '*';

class MyLogger {
  public function log( $msg ) {
    print_r( $msg . "<br />" );
  }
}
$pusher = new Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$logger = new MyLogger();
$pusher->set_logger( $logger );
$data['message'] = 'hello world';
$result = $pusher->trigger('test_channel', 'my_event', array( 'hello' => 'world' ));
$logger->log( "---- My Result ---" );
$logger->log( $result );
```

And the answer I have is:

```
Pusher: ->trigger received string channel "test_channel". Converting to array. Pusher: create_curl( http://api.pusherapp.com:80/apps/*/events?auth_key=*&auth_signature=*&auth_timestamp=*&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=*) Pusher: trigger POST: {"name":"my_event","data":"{\"hello\":\"world\"}","channels":["test_channel"]} Pusher: exec_curl response: Array ( [body] => Unknown auth_key [status] => 400 ) ---- My Result ---
```

What am I doing wrong?

What I want is to send notifications from the server.

Answer (score 7):

I *suspect* your `cluster` might be wrong.

When you create a Pusher application on [dashboard.pusher.com](http://dashboard.pusher.com), you're asked to choose a `cluster`:

[image]

[`pusher-http-php-master`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php) connects to `mt1 (us-east-1)` by default. If you chose another cluster - like `eu (eu-west-1)` - you'll need to be explicit:

```
$pusher = new Pusher(
  $app_key,
  $app_secret,
  $app_id,
  array( 'cluster' => 'eu' ) 
);
```

If that doesn't work, I would <strike>**double**</strike>  **triple** check your `$app_secret`.

Comment: For me just changing the cluster in the pusher settings didn't solve the problem. I also had to go to `Pusher.php` and manually change the host in line 57 from `api.pusherapp.com` to `api-eu.pusher.com`. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when i was using Pusher with Lumen. For me what worked was i removed the package from composer and reinstalled  the package.

first

```
composer remove pusher/pusher-php-server
```

then

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```